# Edge Case: Kendo Web UI Grid 'Select' method not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am experiencing what appears to be an edge case with the Kendo UI framework. Specifically, I am using the **Grid 'Select' method** as documented at [Kendo Web UI API documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-select).

```
var gridWibble= $("#gridWibble").data("kendoGrid");
gridWibble.select("td:eq(0)");

var gridShizzle= $("#gridShizzle").data("kendoGrid");
gridShizzle.select("td:eq(0)");
```

For the purposes of communication, I'll refer to `gridWibble` as the *first grid,* because it is defined first and appears first in the DOM. I'll refer to `gridShizzle` as the *second grid,* because it is defined second and comes second in the DOM. Both grids are created with the correct (and different) IDs and exist in the DOM. Clearly, I have two grids, with different IDs and these are functioning as expected apart from as follows.

**When I try to select a cell in the second grid, as shown in the (last two lines of the) code above, it makes the selection in the first grid (gridWibble). That is to say, it selects the correct cell, but does so in the incorrect grid. Obviously I am expecting it to make the selection in the second grid (gridShizzle). Incidentally, the gridWibble selection code works as expected.**

If I remove the first grid from the DOM (e.g. using Chrome Developer tools) and run the same code in the Console, it successfully selects the appropriate cell in the appropriate (and only) grid `gridShizzle`. The only difference is that there is now only one grid in the DOM.

Can anyone else replicate this when using two Kendo Grids on the same page, and using the Grid Select API method?

**EDIT 1**

> ```
>           gridWibble= $("#gridWibble").kendoGrid({
>               dataSource: {
>                   type: "json",
>                   data: gridWibbleData,
>                   autoSync: true,
>                   pageSize: 500,
>                   serverPaging: false,
>                   serverFiltering: false,
>                   serverSorting: false
>               },
>               columns : [
>                   { field: "Pair", title: "Pair"}, 
>                   { field: "D1", title: "1d"}, 
>                   { field: "D5", title: "1w (5d)"},
>                   { field: "D10", title: "2w (10d)"}, 
>                   { field: "D20", title: "1m (20d)"}, 
>                   { field: "D40", title: "2m (40d)"}, 
>                   { field: "D60", title: "3m (60d)"}, 
>                   { field: "D120", title: "6m (120d)"}, 
>                   { field: "D240", title: "12m (240d)" }
>               ],
>               toolbar: kendo.template($("#gridWibbleTemplate").html()),
>               pageable: true,
>               change: gridChange,
>               dataBound: onDataBound,
>               selectable: "multiple cell",
>               navigatable: true,
>               filterable: true,
>               sortable: true,
>               reorderable: true,
>               resizable: true,
>               columnMenu: false
>           });
>
>           gridShizzle= $("#gridShizzle").kendoGrid({
>               dataSource: {
>                   type: "json",
>                   data: gridShizzleData,
>                   autoSync: true,
>                   pageSize: 500,
>                   serverPaging: false,
>                   serverFiltering: false,
>                   serverSorting: false
>               },
>               columns : [
>                   { field: "Pair", title: "Pair"}, 
>                   { field: "ON", title: "ON"}, 
>                   { field: "W1", title: "1w"},
>                   { field: "W2",  title: "2w"}, 
>                   { field: "M1", title: "1m"}, 
>                   { field: "M2", title: "2m"}, 
>                   { field: "M3", title: "3m"}, 
>                   { field: "M6", title: "6m"}, 
>                   { field: "M9", title: "9m" },
>                   { field: "Y1", title: "1y" }
>               ],
>               toolbar: kendo.template($("#gridShizzleTemplate").html()),
>               pageable: true,
>               change: gridChange,
>               dataBound: onDataBound,
>               selectable: "multiple cell",
>               navigatable: true,
>               filterable: true,
>               sortable: true,
>               reorderable: true,
>               resizable: true,
>               columnMenu: false
>           });
> ```

Comment: I assume it might not be intended for multiple grids? Looks like the "select" not looks in the respective ID, but grabs the overall first TD in the DOM. What happens if you use it as follow? ( just to verify ) `gridShizzle.select("#gridShizzle td:eq(0)");`

Comment: Can you post more of your kendo init code?

Comment: @carter: Kendo UI Init code posted.

Comment: @Basti: gridShizzle.select("#gridShizzle td:eq(0)"); works as I would hope!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off the feedback from @Basti, it is possible to address the correct Grid by using the Grid ID directly in the jQuery selector. For example. `("#gridShizzle td:eq(0)");` as opposed to just `("#td:eq(0)");`. Nonetheless, this still doesn't function as I would expect based on the Kendo UI documentation. Here, it suggests that the method would work just fine having already specified the kendoGrid.